# How Can I Change X Labels In Pandas Plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got an Excel Worksheet that has columns of specific statuses, I need a count of each status and then I need it to be graphed in a bar plot. Example:

```
Status_1    Status_2    Status_3
Active      Abandoned   Active
Inactive    Abandoned   Active
```

Currently I've been using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
report = r"\\Myserver\Reports\Report.xlsx"
df1 = pd.read_excel(report, sheetname=1)
df = df1[['Status_1', 'Status_2', 'Status_3']].copy()

val1 = df['Status_2'].value_counts().to_frame()
vals1 = pd.DataFrame(val1)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
vals1.plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[0,0])
```

So my problem now is that the graph displays properly, but the columns on the X axis are labeled with their statuses (Active/Inactive) and the legend shows the column name (Status_1). I'd like this to be reversed and have the X axis *only* show "Status_1" and the legend to be color coded with two choices of "Active" and "Inactive".

Because I'm doing this with value counts it's gotten be very confused and turned around. Is there any way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: df1[['Status_1', 'Status_2', 'Status_3']].plot(kind='bar')

Comment: Won't that only work if I have numeric data? Can I get value counts for each column in the same dataframe? I was under the impression that `df[column].value_counts().to_frame()` was for one column at a time?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Yes, and it won't work because they're not numeric values, they're strings of text i.e. "Active" "Inactive". I need turn those into counts and then graph that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([['a','i'],['a','i'],['i','a']], columns=["S1", "S2"])
a.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).transpose().plot.bar()
```

[image: a looks like this]

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

a.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()) - creates a dataframe of counted values from your data,

.transpose() - transpose index and columns (in case if you want to go back to having Status1, Status2 as your bars and Active/Inactive as x-label, just remove this method,

plot.bar() - just plots your DataFrame

Comment: This works great! Is there any way to move the statuses to a legend or something instead of beneath each column on the X axis? One status title 'Completion Construction Status' is a bit long and it gets cut off in the plot.

Comment: You can rotate x labels to make it more visible with plt.xticks(rotation=45), or make the whole graph horizontal - instead of bar() use barh(), or you can just rename the xlabels by plt.xticks(range(3),('asa','sab','cas'),rotation=45). Hope that helps, I don't know if you can make a legend of labels.

Comment: Works great! One final question, is there any way to add labels innately to the tops of the columns for a total count?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/), along with reshaping you dataframe into a [tidy form](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
    Status_1   Status_2   Status_3
0     Active  Abandoned     Active
1   Inactive  Abandoned  Abandoned
2     Active  Abandoned     Active
3   Inactive   Inactive     Active
4     Active  Abandoned   Inactive
5  Abandoned  Abandoned     Active

In [27]: df2 = pd.melt(df) # convert into tidy data
In [28]: df2
Out[28]: 
    variable      value
0   Status_1     Active
1   Status_1   Inactive
2   Status_1     Active
3   Status_1   Inactive
4   Status_1     Active
[...]
15  Status_3     Active
16  Status_3   Inactive
17  Status_3     Active
In [29]: sns.factorplot(data=df2, x="variable", kind="count", hue="value")
```

[image: factorplot]

Or:

```
sns.factorplot(data=df2, x="variable", kind="count", col="value")
```

[image: factoroplot]

HTH